# Display jpg in an html with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an html + javascript file. I want it to display the images in a folder. I've got this.

```
  <div id="fotos"></div>

  <script>
  let n = 5;
  let gallery = document.getElementById('fotos') ;
  for (let i = 1; i<= n; i++){
  gallery.innerHTML += '<img class="tfoto" src="folder/'+ i +'.jpg"><br>';
  }
  </script>
```

My problem is:

How can I make it read ALL of the pictures in the folder with NO need to change the file names by a number?

Comment: I don't think you can do this on the client side as it would create a number of security issues.  You can do this on the backend, on the server.  Are you using php?

Comment: No, just html...

Comment: you're out of luck.

Comment: If you wish.. you can enable directory listing in the server, and use AJAX to fetch the files names, and loop over those names :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `Image()`, something like below :

```html
<script>
  let n = 5;
  let gallery = document.getElementById('fotos') ;
  for (let i = 1; i<= n; i++){
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = "folder/"+ i +".jpg";
  gallery.appendChild(img);
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript knows nothing about what's happening on the server, and the server doesn't know what's happening in javascript. To automatically read all files in the server folder you must generate file names in some server language. You can also do the same manually. As for changing names, you don't have to do it. You can use a code similar to the one below.

```js
    var arr=['a.jpg','b.png','c.jpg'];
    var s='';
    function add(el) { 
      s+="<img class='tfoto' src='folder/"+el+"'><br>";
    }
    arr.forEach(add);
    var gallery = document.getElementById('fotos');
    gallery.innerHTML=s;
    // for test:
    console.log(s);
```

```html
<div id='fotos'></div>
```